# Field 'blah_1' doesn't have a default value when there is no such field

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save a new object of, we'll say, model type Apple to the Django ORM (MySQL backend) with the Django .save() method. However, I'm getting a "Field 'blah_1' doesn't have a default value" error. The weird thing is, there *is* no 'blah_1' field for Apple objects, and I don't think I've assigned to this nonexistent field anywhere either. There *is* a 'blah_fk_1' field, but I'm quite certain there is no 'blah_1' field. What could possibly be causing this problem?

Edit: I can only provide so much detail, some of the code is sensitive. However, I can verify that `'blah_1' in apple._meta.get_all_field_names()` (where `apple` is an Apple object) yields False; i.e. the 'blah_1' field does not exist. I can also verify that if you try to assign to a field that doesn't exist, you get AttributeError: 'Apple' object has no attribute 'blah_1'. Since this error has not arisen, I know that I have not assigned to the non-existent field at any point.

Edit 2: Here's the traceback (with some extra cruft from using pdb):

```
:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1314, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "DRP/management/commands/make_apples.py", line 14, in handle
    create_new_apples(lab_group, debug=debug, bare_debug=debug)
  File "DRP/apple/apple.py", line 880, in create_new_apples
    store_new_Apple_list(lab_group, [[conf]+rec], debug=debug)
  File "DRP/database_construction.py", line 188, in store_new_Apple_list
    new_rec.save() #Store this apple in the database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1511, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 898, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 176, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
Warning: Field 'blah_1' doesn't have a default value
```

Edit 3: So even though this field is not referenced in the code anywhere at all, it turns out upon inspection of the MySQL database that the column still exists in the database, from some time before I was working on this code. What can I do about this?

Comment: Hi there. Can you post the model code for your "`Apple`" model? There may not be enough information in your post for us to be able to help you

Comment: and the error traceback would be helpful.

Comment: make sure your migrations are getting applied.

Comment: Do you use VCS? Probably, there *was* field `blah_1`, but it was not correctly removed from database layer.

Comment: @soon was correct: at some point in the past (before I was a part of this team) the fields were removed from the code but not in migrations applied to the database. soon, if you want to provide that as an answer in the near future I will accept it, otherwise I will post it and accept it myself, as I discovered it before seeing your response.

Comment: So, @John was right too. I believe, John should post the answer.

Comment: @soon go ahead and post the answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like, there *was* field `blah_1` in your model, but it was not correctly removed from database layer.

You could try to find the commit, where the field was removed (in case, if you are using VCS), probably, it also contains the migration.

You could also try to run `./manage.py makemigrations <your_app_name>` in order to create migration, or [write it yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/).